# Does it get harder to farm silver & experience after beating the final boss?

Tags: prime-world-defenders

In Prime World Defenders you can always go back and replay previous levels rather than progressing the story, and you get a little bit of experience and silver for doing so. Starting from when you reach the first boss level, however, you have another option: three randomly generated "farming" levels (easy, medium, and hard) appear, offering better silver and experience than you would get from replaying an old level as well as a chest, and being replaced by a new randomly generated level when beaten.

I'm at the final boss level, and I think I can take him, but there are still quite a few towers I'd like to finish leveling up. If I beat the final boss, will the easy/medium/hard farming levels still be available, or will I have to make do with replaying previous story levels to get more silver & experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

The easy/medium/hard farming levels are still available after defeating the final boss, and will continue to refresh when beaten.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why does this screenshot remind me of Defender's Quest?